# Use two INT values as Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MariaDB/MySQL DB with several columns, two of them are named "Year" (2018, 2019, 2020 etc.) and "Month" (01, 02, 03 etc.) but store values as INT.

How can I (in a MySQL SELECT phrase) select those two and combine them as a Date value (SELECT ... AS xyz) to have them as MONTH-YEAR (2019-04, 2019-05 etc.)?

Because I have to do a WHERE later where I only want to have the last twelve months (- INTERVAL 12 MONTH).  And when the month changes (e.g. to June 2020) I don't need May from 2019 anymore etc.
That's why I need to have them as a Date (I guess) to do the proper calculation with "- INTERVAL [...]".

Comment: You could express as (yyyy * 12) + mm

Comment: If you want to use functionality for Date/Time datatype you should use a Date type column in your table

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last 12 months, you can "month" arithmetic:

```
where year * 12 + month >= year(curdate()) * 12 + month(curdate()) - 12
```

This converts your columns and the current date to the number of months since time 0.